# How does spacy use word embeddings for Named Entity Recognition (NER)?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I'm trying to train an NER model using `spaCy` to identify locations, (person) names, and organisations. I'm trying to understand how `spaCy` recognises entities in text and I've not been able to find an answer. From [this issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/491) on Github and [this example](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner_standalone.py), it appears that spaCy uses a number of features present in the text such as POS tags, prefixes, suffixes, and other character and word-based features in the text to train an Averaged Perceptron.

However, nowhere in the code does it appear that `spaCy` uses the GLoVe embeddings (although each word in the sentence/document appears to have them, if present in the GLoVe corpus).

My questions are -

1. Are these used in the NER system now?
2. If I were to switch out the word vectors to a different set, should I expect performance to change in a meaningful way?
3. Where in the code can I find out how (if it all) `spaCy` is using the word vectors?

I've tried looking through the Cython code, but I'm not able to understand whether the labelling system uses word embeddings.

Comment: Did you find out anything? I'd love the same information.

Comment: Sadly, no - I wasn't able to and eventually gave up the search. I used MITIE instead - https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE/.

Comment: See an answer on the internals of the spaCy NER [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381170/which-deep-learning-algorithm-does-spacy-uses-when-we-train-custom-model/60394246#60394246).

Answer (score 22):

spaCy does use word embeddings for its NER model, which is a multilayer CNN. There's a quite a nice video that Matthew Honnibal, the creator of spaCy made, about how its NER works [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqDHBH9IjRU). All three English models use GloVe vectors trained on Common Crawl, but the smaller models "prune" the number of vectors by having similar words mapped to the same vector [link](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom-vectors-coverage).

It's quite doable to add custom vectors. There's an overview of the process in the spaCy [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom), plus some example code on [Github](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/vectors_fast_text.py).

Comment: Four years member and never finished the tour ;-)

Comment: More information (derived from the youtube video) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381170/which-deep-learning-algorithm-does-spacy-uses-when-we-train-custom-model/60394246#60394246)